# Html5: redirecting user

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, jquery-mobile

I have this code in my html file. within the body tag, I have several pages identified by their ids i.e. page1, page2 and so forth. how do I redirect my user to a page with id="page8". my javascript is as follows and its working fine.I have tried to place **windows.location('#pag8')** in the code below but when I press the submit button the user is redirected before validation his inputs. Where do I place it or how I use **header** on the server side to accomplish this? **header('location: /page8')** gives errors

```
<script>

function onSuccess(data, status)
    {

        data = $.trim(data);
        $("#notification").text(data);


    }

    function onError(data, status)
    {
        // handle an error
    }        

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#pass-signup").click(function(){

            var formData = $("#passengerfrmsignup").serialize();
            $('#passengerfrmsignup')[0].reset();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "passenger.php",
                cache: false,
                data: formData,
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
            });             
            $( "#hidden" ).show();
            return false;

        });



    });

</script>
```

Comment: JQM has its own method for page navigation ( $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#page8", { transition: "slide"  });)  you place it after the ajax call. You don't need ($(document).ready(function() { ...) go to the JQM site and see Page and mobile Events to understand them.

Comment: I placed after the ajax call but nothing seems to happen I mean no redirect at all

Comment: do you see any errors in the browsers console,or in the apache error log file? maybe you are having errors which stops the script from running